# How do you use a single select dropdown with Rails has_many through association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activerecord, drop-down-menu

I can't figure out how to get a single select dropdown for a Rails has_many through association to work. I can only get multiple checkboxes or a multiple-select to work.

How do you have a rails has_many through relationship where you want the user to only be able to select one option from the associated collection through a single select drop down?

Here are my models

```
class Artist < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :topics
  has_many :quotes, through: :topics
end

class Topic < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :quote
end

class Quote < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :topics
  has_many :artists, through: :topics
end
```

Here is my create action and params in the Quotes controller:

```
  def create
    @quote = current_user.quotes.build(quote_params)
    if @quote.save
      flash[:success] = "Quote created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end
```

And here are the form fields that work:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:artist_ids, Artist.all, :id, :name,
      {}, { :multiple => true } ) %>

<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:artist_ids, Artist.all, :id, :name ) %>
```

If I use this to make a single select drop down it just displays the dropdown with the correct collection, but then doesn't seem to save on submit and doesn't display in the view:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:artist_ids, Artist.all, :id, :name ) %>
```

For the two form fields that do work I can display the results in the view with this:

```
<% quote.artists.each do |artist| %>
  <%= artist.name %> - It worked!
<% end %>
```

But I don't want a multi-select dropdown. I just want a dropdown where you can only select and submit one option. How do you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! exactly, I had the same problem but I have solved by using own tricks, see the below code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Artist</label>
    <select name="quote[artist_ids][]" id="quote_artist_ids" class="form-control">
        <% Artist.all.each do |artist| %>
            <option value="<%= artist.id %>">
                <%= artist.name %>
            </option>
        <% end %>
    </select>
</div>
```

It's working, without this everything are same like: `quote_params` I mean all are the same which before worked for multiple.

Hope to help

Comment: Wow. Ok that worked! Thank you. ThIs doesn't seem like the correct "Rails Way", so I'd be interested in seeing if anyone knows a more idiomatically correct way to do this, but just happy to see it working finally. Thanks so much.

Comment: Lesson learned: when in doubt, build the form manually in HTML before banging your head against every Rails helper method.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way, by Ruby on Rails:

```
<%= collection_select(:empleado, :departamento_id, Departamento.all, :id, :nombre_departamento, {:prompt => false}) %>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Here's a [help center article](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) on how you can properly format code. Thanks for contributing an answer but can you also add an explanation on how your code solves the problem?